# nc(netcat) cmd output interpretation

Tags: format, netcat

Just a quick question.

I used `nc` cmd like the following.

```
nc -v kvs(=my-redis-host-name) 6379
```

and the output was

```
kvs [127.255.0.2] 6379 (?) open.
```

How can I interpret this? I searched nc cmd output but the output example has different format maybe because base OS is different (I use debian). The format looks like

```
hostname [ip corresponding to host] port (**What is this part?**) connection succeed or fail
```

but I am not sure.

Comment: Seems my guess is almost correct. I got "(?)" when I do the same with docker-compose in local env. what should be inside the round brackets?